# How to display in blade which rows are soft deleted?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have created a polling system and in the backend (CMS area) I want the ability for admins to be able to remove polls. When an admin removes a poll, it should soft delete the poll. This is working as intended, however I also want to have the ability for the admin to be able to restore a poll. To do this I am displaying all of the polls (including the soft deleted polls) in the admin area.

PollController index() to get all polls

```
$polls = Poll::withTrashed()->get();
```

In the blade I want to have two different buttons for each poll. One of restoring and one for deleting but I only want to display 1 button for each poll depending on whether it can be restored or deleted.

To do this, I have put this inside the foreach in the blade:

```
@if($poll->trashed())
// Restore button
@else
// Delete button
@endif
```

However the issue is, trashed() keeps returning true for all the polls when only 1 out of the 3 polls I have are actually soft deleted. I am unsure as to why trashed() returns all of these are true?

How would I get this method working correctly? Thanks.

Comment: The only reason that `trashed()` would return true is when the column `deleted_at` in the table is not null, which means that the record is soft deleted. Is this column null in your polls table?

Comment: @thefallen you're right, that resolved it. Non soft-deleted rows deleted_at columns were set to 0:00:00 but setting to null fixed this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PART 1**
It depends on your query. When using soft deletes, Laravel will query all models that are not soft-deleted by default. When you also want to get the soft-deleted models, you need to call the withTrashed() method on your query. Read more here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models

To understand what `withTrashed()` does, you need to understand how soft-deleting works. Soft-deleting models works by adding a new column to your database tables called deleted_at. It's value defaults to null. When you soft-delete a model, Laravel will put the current timestamp into that column. Therefore, this field doesn't contain a null value anymore.

When querying models when using `soft-deletes`, Laravel appends a deleted_at is null condition to the query. Calling the withTrashed() method, removes that condition from the query.

Have a look on the source of the default query modifier and the withTrashed method.

**PART 2**
That are events. You can call that to tell Laravel, that it should execute that specific closure when this event happens. In your example, it is listening for the "deleting" event. See more on that here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

**PART 3**
You can entirely `delete soft-deletable` models with the `forceDelete()` method. See "Permanently Deleting Models" here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models

**FOR EXAMPLE**

`$items = App\Model::withTrashed()->get();`

If you want to restore a single item, just find it by ID:

`$item = App\Model::find($id);`